# Display Firebase data based on username

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a UITableView displaying posts in the Firebase Database in cells. There is also another UITableView which I would like to display only posts from the user who is logged in.

This is what I currently have in my UserPostViewController:

```
func loadData() {
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for post in postsDictionary {
                self.userPosts.add(post.value)
            }
            self.userPostsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // pass any object as parameter, i.e. the tapped row
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.userPosts.count
}

// Displays posts in postsTableView
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    let post = self.userPosts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
    cell.titleLabel.text = post["title"] as? String
    cell.priceLabel.text = post["price"] as? String
    if let imageName = post["image"] as? String {
        let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageName)")
        imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            cell.titleLabel.alpha = 0
            cell.contentTextView.alpha = 0
            cell.postImageView.alpha = 0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                cell.titleLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.contentTextView.alpha = 1
                cell.postImageView.alpha = 1
            })
        } else {
            print("Error occured during image download: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here is also a picture of what I mean in Firebase:

[image: Here]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a NoSQL database. Trying to project SQL practices on it, is going to cause you grief.

Instead of storing one long list of posts and then using queries to filter, store your posts for each user under a user-specific node. I.e.

```
users
  $uid
    username: "gabe"
posts
  $uid
    -K12348: {
      description: "...."
      image: "...."
    }
```

Now you can access the posts for a specific user with a direct-access read, instead of a query on an ever-growing list:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
    (snapshot) in
    if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        for post in postsDictionary {
            self.userPosts.add(post.value)
        }
        self.userPostsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

*Please post your JSON as text next time, so that I can copy/paste it into my answer.*

I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: I completely understand your idea, however if I was to implement this in my database there would be no way to call all the posts in a UITableView

Comment: That is correct. That's why you model the data for each of your use-cases. Often you'll end up duplicating the data in multiple places. That is normal on NoSQL databases.